# Regular expression 'not match numbers' in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to check if a string is in another string with comma separated. I've write some code and it work like this...

```
$find_number = '3'
$string_to_search = '1,3,124,12'
preg_match('/[^0-9]'.$find_number.'[^0-9]/', string_to_search);
//match

$find_number = '4'
$string_to_search = '1,3,124,12'
preg_match('/[^0-9]'.$find_number.'[^0-9]/', string_to_search);
//not match
```

Which is what I expected. The problem is that the first and last string can't recognized in this expression. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like you forgot `$`at the beginning of your variables.

Comment: why did you use *preg_match*? explode and array comparing is much performer in your case ...

Comment: The `$`s are not the only trouble here.

Comment: @roberto06 thanks for reminding. I've edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to check if there are no digits on both sides of the `$find_number`, and that is why you need `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` lookarounds that do not *consume* text before and after the number you need to match allowing to check the first and last items. The `[^0-9]` in your pattern are *negated character class* instances, that require a character other than a digit before and after the *find_number*. The lookarounds will just fail the match if there is a digit before (`(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind) or after (with `(?!\d)` negative lookahead) the *find_number*. See below:

```
$find_number = '3';
$string_to_search = '1,3,124,12';
if (preg_match('/(?<!\d)'.$find_number.'(?!\d)/', $string_to_search)) {
    echo "match!";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2QEFE8).

An alternative is to use `explode` with [**`in_array`**](http://www.php.net/in_array):

```
$find_number = '3';
$string_to_search = '1,3,124,12';
if (in_array($find_number, explode(",", $string_to_search))) {
    echo "match!";
}
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/kLhnpe)

Comment: Yes, in this context, it is OK to use even word boundaries. Generally speaking, a suitable zero-width assertion that will check the boundary between a digit and a non-digit word boundary being more generic.

Comment: or maybe vice versa *in this context, it is OK to use even lookarounds*

Comment: @revo: I do not actually preach regex only, I think a non-regex `in_array` solution to be the most readable and simple to use in the current scenario. The regex solution is only to show a way to re-use OP pattern in a working regex the main point being consuming and non-consuming pattern types. If we were to talk about regex precision, I'd even go for `(?<=^|,)` (or `(?<![^,])`) and `(?=,|$)` (or `(?![^,])`) lookarounds.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regular expressions for such a simple task. If `$find_number` doesn't contain the separator then you can enclose both `$find_number` and `$string_to_search` in separators and use function [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find out if `$find_number` is present or not in `$string_to_search`. `strpost()` is much faster than `preg_match()`.

```
$find_number = '3';
$string_to_search = '1,3,124,12';

if (strpos(",{$string_to_search},", ",{$find_number},") !== FALSE) {
    echo("{$find_number} is present in {$string_to_search}");
} else {
    echo("No.");
}
```

Wrapping `$find_number` in separators is needed to avoid it finding partial values, wrapping `$string_to_search` in separators is needed to let it find the `$find_number` when it is the first or the last entry in `$string_to_search`.

Comment: @revo what do you mean? It works fine when `$find_number` is `1` because of `!== FALSE`.

Comment: No I meant something else but wasn't aware of additional commas. Upvoted.